# Jabber/XMPP Client for BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, xmpp

I am looking for a Jabber/XMPP client for BlackBerry that I can use with our OpenFire server.

It needs to be able to use the Secure connection from OpenFire either the SSL or TLS.

It needs to be a direct connection to our server, no 3rd party sever in the middle

It needs to be free.

I have tested and JiveTalk works great and we'll use it if I can't find another one, we're just trying to find a free one.

Thanks

Comment: Jabber/XMPP is an open protocol, you could always write it yourself!

Comment: It would be cheaper for me to drop the money on a full OCS server with the MS clients for the BlackBerry's then write my own client because its open souce.  Like I said, we'll buy the Jivetalk if nothing better exists.  This is looking like one of those you get want you pay for area when it comes to clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try http://www.vayusphere.com/vayuxmpp.htm

Supports TLS/SSL, does not use a network resident proxy so connections to your XMPP server are direct, and supports Multi User Chat rooms.

Answer (score 0):

> Try
>   http://www.vayusphere.com/vayuxmpp.htm
>
> Supports TLS/SSL, does not use a
>   network resident proxy so connections
>   to your XMPP server are direct, and
>   supports Multi User Chat rooms.

but its only free for 15 days.

Answer (score 0):

Try www.instango.com or www.talkonaut.com